# Suggestions regarding accessiblity of files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, text, notepad++

Iam trying to make a password manager with login system using python and tkinter. To store those passwords I'm using notepad. But, the problem is that, the passwords are easily accessible just by opening the .txt file(without logging into the app) that I'm using to store them.So, is there any way to make those text files only accessible through that app or any better way to store that information? Please dont mind any mistakes

Comment: why dont you encrypy the textfile and let the program decrypt the passwords

Comment: here is a tutorial on encryption : https://pyshark.com/encrypt-and-decrypt-files-using-python/#:~:text=%20Encrypt%20and%20Decrypt%20Files%20using%20Python%20,our...%204%20Encrypting%20a%20File.%20%20More%20

Comment: @TERMINATOR really thanks sir!!

Comment: its no prblem anything to help

Comment: I provided a secure answer that will not be able to be cracked like using zip files

Comment: Do you need high security, or just simple obfuscation?

Comment: @pepoluan simple obfuscation is sufficient but i would be glad to know both ways. thankyou

Comment: Have a try with [KeePass](https://keepass.info/) Free and OpenSource.

Comment: It is not secure to use Python script as the password manager because it is easy to modify the script to show the decrypted password even though the stored password is encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you encrypt the file to ensure people can not read your usernames and passwords.Encryption is a process of converting information into some form of a code to hide its true content. The only way to access the file information then is to decrypt it. The process of encryption/decryption is called cryptography.

Cryptogrophy is the encryption library in python

so first type `pip install cryptography` to install the cryptogrophy libary

so I first suggest you encrypt your usernames like so:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

key = Fernet.generate_key()

with open('mykey.key', 'rb') as mykey:
    key = mykey.read()

print(key)

f = Fernet(key)

with open('grades.csv', 'rb') as original_file:
    original = original_file.read()

encrypted = f.encrypt(original)

with open ('enc_grades.csv', 'wb') as encrypted_file:
    encrypted_file.write(encrypted)

with open('mykey.key', 'wb') as mykey:
    mykey.write(key)
```

I then suggest you decrypt the file temposrarrly like so:

```
class Encryptor():

    def key_create(self):
        key = Fernet.generate_key()
        return key

    def key_write(self, key, key_name):
        with open(key_name, 'wb') as mykey:
            mykey.write(key)

    def key_load(self, key_name):
        with open(key_name, 'rb') as mykey:
            key = mykey.read()
        return key


    def file_encrypt(self, key, original_file, encrypted_file):
        
        f = Fernet(key)

        with open(original_file, 'rb') as file:
            original = file.read()

        encrypted = f.encrypt(original)

        with open (encrypted_file, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(encrypted)

    def file_decrypt(self, key, encrypted_file, decrypted_file):
        
        f = Fernet(key)

        with open(encrypted_file, 'rb') as file:
            encrypted = file.read()

        decrypted = f.decrypt(encrypted)

        with open(decrypted_file, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(decrypted)
```

Then delete the decrypted file once you got the usernames like so:

```
import os
os.remove(Decrypted_file)
```

Comment: Why Fernet? Why not PyCryptodome instead?

Comment: beacsuse Fernet is a part of a larger more mainstream libary called cryptogrohpy but PyCryptodome also work

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the way you're going about doing this.

First, you shouldn't be storing actual passwords. Instead, hash them and store the hashes, then when your users try to log in, you hash the passwords they give and check that it matches the hash you have stored for them.

Second, your app should be running under a service account and whatever secrets it needs should be accessible only to that account, which prevents any other user from being able to read its sensitive data. For added protection, you can disable ssh and shell access for that service account, and also disable sudo and root logins on your server to make it a bit harder for an attacker to become the service account (be aware it doesn't make it impossible, just harder).

Third, you shouldn't be rolling your own secrets manager anyway. But assuming this is some sort of toy app or school project where you're doing it to learn how to do it, keep some basic rules of info sec in mind. You can also encrypt the file you keep the password hashes in, but don't think that necessarily buys more security as anyone who can get access to your service account to read the password file at all can also get the encryption key. This is the basic reason /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow aren't encrypted and are instead protected by restrictive file permissions.

Mind you, a user database in a flat text file isn't particularly scalable, so while it works fine for servers, apps with a lot of accounts tend to use real databases, and you can use the database manager's built-in access control and encryption functionality to restrict access to sensitive tables and encrypt sensitive columns.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to do that!
But for that we need to use encryption:

The advantages of using a zip file is that it will save some space, and it is not easy to read and edit in a text editor (binary data). It can be easily manipulated in your Python Script:

```
with ZipFile('spam.zip') as myzip:
    with myzip.open('eggs.txt') as myfile:
        print(myfile.read())
```

It is as simple as that! A temp file on the other hand, is a volatile (delete=True/False) file and can be discarded once you are done with it. You can easily copy its contents to another file or zip it before you close it as mentioned above.

```
with open tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
    temp.write(b"Binary Data")
```

Again, another easy process. However, you must zip or encrypt it to achieve the final result. Now, moving on to encryption. The easiest way is an XOR cipher. Since we are simply trying to prevent 'readability' and not concerned about security, you can do the following:
recommended solution (XOR cipher):

```
from itertools import cycle


def xorcize(data, key):
    """Return a string of xor mutated data."""
    return "".join(chr(ord(a)^ord(b)) for a, b in zip(data, cycle(key)))


data = "Your secret passwords"
key = "This is the encryption key"

encdata = xorcize(data, key)
decdata = xorcize(encdata, key)

print(data, encdata, decdata, sep="\n")
```

Notice how small that function is? It is quite convenient to include it in any of your scripts. All your data can be encrypted before writing them to a file, and save it using a file extension such as ".dat" or ".contacts" or any custom name you choose. Make sure it is not opened in an editor by default (such as ".txt", ".nfo").

Comment: if someone cant open it with notepad they can use nano in terminal for custom file extensions

Comment: Zip is not a realiable enecryption method please find a reliable solution

Comment: Yes, but notepad and nano in the terminal show the same thing when trying to display a plain text .txt file

Comment: but nano can open a custom extension, thats what I am saying

Comment: But in the end, I think Zip will still be a lot simpler than other solutions.

Comment: zip has a way of losing data if it is used to much

Comment: I don't even know why I ama explaining myself to someone who doesn't know what they are talking about

Comment: But not if it's encrypted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226695/discussion-between-terminator-and-ridwan).

Answer (score 0):

If you just need simple obfuscation, just compress with [`lzma`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma.html#module-lzma).

```py
import lzma
import pickle

def save_data(data, filename):
    with lzma.open(filename, "wb") as fout:
        pickle.dump(data, fout, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

def read_data(filename):
    with lzma.open(filename, "rb") as fin:
        return pickle.load(fin)


important_data_to_obfuscate = { ... }  # I'm assuming it's some kind of dict
save_data(important_data_to_obfuscate, "userdata.bin")
copy_of_important_data = read_data("userdata.bin")
assert important_data_to_obfuscate == copy_of_important_data
```